# How to check if two string are of the same length?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if two string are of the same length. I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
string passnew = "1233";
string passcnfrm = "1234";

if((passnew.Length&&passcnfrm.Length)>6 ||(passnew.Length&&passcnfrm.Length)<15)
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Why does it not work? What do I need to change?

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to get - what does 6 and 15 has to do with the length being the same?

Comment: I edited the question a bit; I hope I didn't accidentally remove any detail...

Comment: Make sure to check your logic too. Once you correct the syntax, your current condition is true if both strings are longer than 6 **or** both strings are shorter than 15. It is true when both strings are empty, or both strings have a length of 256. Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: I'm feeling some kind of unsecure if someone who writes some security login fails on such a problem. ;-)

Comment: Not wanting to be harsh, but I seriously wonder if you have a genuine interest in programming.

Comment: @Oliver - Not only that, but the fact that the password appears to have a length restriction means it's probably going to be stored in plain text rather than salted and hashed, which is another gigantic fail.

Comment: Greg - come on, never mind how true, that's the least of the issues here I reckon.

Comment: OP's question is around passwords having the same length. So coming up with `(passnew.Length==passcnfrm.Length)` is all that OP needs in this instance. I'm guessing the range check is some existing code not written by OP. Judging by the question, the rangecheck may only confuse the OP more, thinking this is now necessary for length equality checks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(passnew.Length == passcnfrm.Length && 
   passnew.Length > 6 && passnew.Length < 15)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Also consider checking equality of passwords. To do so, replace `passnew.Length == passcnfrm.Length` with `passnew == passcnfrm`

Comment: @Scoregraphic, I do agree, but since OP asked for "same length", I'll keep this untouched, ty for your comment

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some basic syntax lessons. What you write inside of these brackets are conditions. We have unary operators (operating on one thing), binary operators (two) and one tertiary operator (forget about that one).

You cannot construct something like your "boundary test" with those easily.

A possible way:

```
(passnew.Length > 6) && (passcnfrm.Length > 6)
```

But you aren't testing if the length is equal anyway, even if you could use a syntax like that. You seem to want to compare if both are longer than 6 chars and shorter than 15 chars. One at 7 and one at 14 would satisfy both conditions..

Comment: Never mind syntax. Clearly not even close to correct in any form of pseudo code.

Comment: Just one little detail, operators (or functions) taking three arguments are called ternary, not tertiary.

Comment: @Matajon Ouch. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll let the answer stay like that to show off my stupidity and remind me to proof read better in next answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(passnew.Length == passcnfrm.Length && 
   (passnew.Length < 15 && passnew.Length > 6))
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Checks both are same length, and either one is more than 6 and less than 15 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

that would be:

```
if(passcnfrm.Length.Equals(passnew.Length))
 {
   //do stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A probably better way to do it is:

```
if (( passnew != null && passcnfrm != null )
    ( passnew == passcnfrm )
&&  ( passnew.Length > 6 && passnew.Length < 15 ))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Hides the length check inside the equality check which you'll probably need, it isn't in your question but the variable names make it pretty clear you're doing a password change function there. I added the null check to make sure the length checks don't throw a NullReferenceException, not needed in the example because you assign both manually, but might save some trouble if you're going to convert this to a method later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:
if (s.Contains(s1[i]))

or:

boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString);

or use this method:

public static int occurrence(string [] a, string a2)
        {
            int occ = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length;i++ )
            {
                if(a[i].Equals(a2))
                {
                    occ++;
                }

```
        }
        return occ;
    }
```